# how to integrate mailjet send API to Node.js route?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mailjet

I have been trying to integrate my Mailjet transactional template to my "new contact" route in order to send the email when a new contact register on my website form for newsletter but it still show me an error 401 when submitting the form. No email is received and obviously none is sent...

If anyone has encountered this problem before I would really appreciate if he could put me on the right track !

Thank you very much in advance for your return guys !

Here is both my routes GET and POST for "contact":

```
router.get('/contact', function(req, res, next) {
 mongoose.model('contacts').find(
 function(err, contact){
  res.render('contact', {contact, isLoggedIn});
 });
});


router.post('/contact', function(req, res, next) {
var newContact = new contactModel({
contactName: req.body.contactName,
contactEmail: req.body.contactEmail,
contactPhone: req.body.contactPhone,
contactMessage: req.body.contactMessage,
contactNews: req.body.contactNews
});

newContact.save(
function(error, contact){
  mongoose.model('contacts').find(
  function(err, contact){
  req.session.contact = contact;
  res.render('index', {contact, isLoggedIn});
})
})

contactModel.find(
{
  _id: req.body._id
},

function(err, contact) {

const request = mailjet
    .post("send", {'version': 'v3.1'})
    .request({
        "Messages":[
            {
            "From": {
                "Email": "xxxx@hotmail.fr",
                "Name": "xx"
            },
            "To": [
                {
                "Email":req.body.contactEmail,
                "Name": req.body.contactName
                }
            ],
            "TemplateID": xxxx,
            "TemplateLanguage": true,
            "Subject": "xxx",
            "Variables": {}
        }
        ]
    })
request
    .then((result) => {
        console.log(result.body)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err.statusCode)
    })
 });
});
module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Did you set your public and private key when defining mailjet ?
Like `const mailjet = require ('node-mailjet').connect(MJ_APIKEY_PUBLIC,MJ_APIKEY_PRIVATE)`

Comment: yes I did I put it at the beginning of the file